# Basic ajax get request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I'm making a calendar with 2 links, one to go back a month and the other to go forward a month.

This is my cal.php File:

```
<div class='cal_wrapper' id='cal'>
 <?php
   echo "<a href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Prev Month</a>";
   echo "<a href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Next Month</a>";

   echo $calendar;

 ?>
 </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to use jquery/ajax to update the what's inside the cal_wrapper div without having to refresh the page. I've look hard but can't find any examples of getting this done without using an HTML form.  How can I send 2 variables through a GET request, month and year, should be pretty basic..but I'm going cross eyed trying to find something on the internets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give your link classes

```
echo "<a class='month_selector' href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Prev Month</a>";
echo "<a class='month_selector' href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Next Month</a>";
```

Then load the contents of the ajax request into the wrapper div whenever one of those links has been clicked.

```
$('#cal_wrapper a.month_selector').live(function(e){
     $('#cal_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') ); 
     e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

EDIT you can use .load to load page fragments using the #wrapper_div

```
$('#cal_wrapper a.month_selector').live('click', function(e){
     $('#cal_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #wrapper_div' ); 
     e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

So wrap your cal_wrapper div in #wrapper_div and the code above will only load the contents of wrapper div. Use live instead of click since you are dynamically inserting the links.

Comment: Look at your console, what kind of errors are you getting, if any ?

Comment: the problem is double quotes at class attribute.

Comment: This has been doing what it's supposed to be doing. Another issue I'm running into is that this calendar is part of a larger page, with a lot more content.  So when I click the prev/next link it's loading the entire page in the cal_wrapper div. How can I just update what in the cal_wrapper div?

Answer (score 0):

Just correcting the answer above. You need to use the jquery method "live", because the content of the cal_wrapper div will change (whenever you click on 'next/prev' link)

Put the contents below in a "main file". The first load (inside onready) will load the first month and year.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.call_wrapper').load('cal.php?month=m&year=y');

    $('.cal_wrapper a.pagination').live('click', function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.cal_wrapper').load(link); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>

<div class='cal_wrapper' id='cal'></div>
```

And your cal.php (remove the div tag from inside it)

```php
<?php
    echo "<a class="pagination" href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Prev Month</a>";
    echo "<a class="pagination" href='cal.php?month=m&year=y'>Next Month</a>";

    echo $calendar;
?>
```

Comment: Getting an error on your javascript you provided.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
homepage_cal_test.php:18Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Include jquery before the js tag (inside the iframe)

Comment: It was, still not working.  BTW On my main page, I have included the cal.php page. I'm not  using iframes. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: There was an error in the script. Fixed. (after e.preventDefault())